# How do I implement "Range("AC2:AC51").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, _ Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True" in python

Tags: python, excel, vba, linear-regression

I have an old Excel document with some VBA code in it and I'm not really sure what it's doing.
`Sheets("1").Range("AC2:AC51").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True`

I'd like to implement this in python to understand what exactly is going on. Any hints?

I found [Range.DataSeries method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.DataSeries) but there is no explanation.

Update:
I was a bit annoyed by the VBA script and forgot to write what I did already.
I ran the script with these input values:
12.04, 12.04, 12.04, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.043, 12.042, 12.043, 12.043, 12.043, 12.043, 12.044, 12.043, 12.044, 12.044, 12.044, 12.045, 12.044, 12.045, 12.045, 12.044, 12.044, 12.044, 12.045, 12.045, 12.046, 12.045, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.045, 12.046, 12.046, 12.047, 12.046, 12.046

and got those results:
12.0407, 12.0408, 12.0409, 12.0411, 12.0412, 12.0413, 12.0414, 12.0416, 12.0417, 12.0418, 12.0420, 12.0421, 12.0422, 12.0424, 12.0425, 12.0426, 12.0427, 12.0429, 12.0430, 12.0431, 12.0433, 12.0434, 12.0435, 12.0437, 12.0438, 12.0439, 12.0441, 12.0442, 12.0443, 12.0444, 12.0446, 12.0447, 12.0448, 12.0450, 12.0451, 12.0452, 12.0454, 12.0455, 12.0456, 12.0458, 12.0459, 12.0460, 12.0461, 12.0463, 12.0464, 12.0465, 12.0467, 12.0468, 12.0469, 12.0471

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: If you want to understand what is going on, wouldn't it be easier to run the VBA and inspect the output in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [12.04, 12.04, 12.04, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.041, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.042, 12.043, 12.042, 12.043, 12.043, 12.043, 12.043, 12.044, 12.043, 12.044, 12.044, 12.044, 12.045, 12.044, 12.045, 12.045, 12.044, 12.044, 12.044, 12.045, 12.045, 12.046, 12.045, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.046, 12.045, 12.046, 12.046, 12.047, 12.046, 12.046]
vba_result = [12.0407, 12.0408, 12.0409, 12.0411, 12.0412, 12.0413, 12.0414, 12.0416, 12.0417, 12.0418, 12.0420, 12.0421, 12.0422, 12.0424, 12.0425, 12.0426, 12.0427, 12.0429, 12.0430, 12.0431, 12.0433, 12.0434, 12.0435, 12.0437, 12.0438, 12.0439, 12.0441, 12.0442, 12.0443, 12.0444, 12.0446, 12.0447, 12.0448, 12.0450, 12.0451, 12.0452, 12.0454, 12.0455, 12.0456, 12.0458, 12.0459, 12.0460, 12.0461, 12.0463, 12.0464, 12.0465, 12.0467, 12.0468, 12.0469, 12.0471]

# generate numbers from 1 to 50
n = np.linspace(1, 50, 50)
# calculate the linear regression
lr = sp.stats.linregress(n, data)

# calculate the fitted lines values
s = [*map(lambda x: round(lr.slope * x + lr.intercept, 4), n)]
vba_result == s

# visualise the data
plt.subplots(dpi=300)
plt.plot(n, data, '.', label='data')
plt.plot(n, lr.intercept + lr.slope * n, label='fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```